# Virtualization is not available within ubuntu image that was installed through virtual box on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have windows 7 system where virtual box is installed and virtualization is enabled.

[image]

In virtual box I have installed ubuntu image that is also have installed virtualbox. But within that box virtualization is not avaible.

[image]

Is it possible to enable virtualization for such case?

Comment: Of course you can't. And what would be the point of this? Infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer. The main problem that I have windows operation system that can not be changed. And my main goal is to set up vagrant+ansible on some linux box, because ansible is not officially supported on windows system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is called Nested Virtualization. Not every piece of hardware can do it.

See: ["Nested virtualization" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_virtualization)

Comment: VirtualBox does not currently support nested virtualization.